# Loading AngularJS combined directive templates with NgInclude

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, angularjs-directive

I want to include all of my directive templates within a single file to reduce the number of HTTP requests required to load a directive heavy page.

I have this directive

```
angular.module('bwDirectives', [])
    .directive('bwInfoCard', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            transclude: false,
            replace: true,
            scope: { title: '=' },
            templateUrl: "one-template",
        };
    })
```

If I specify the templates in-line like this then it loads the directive template properly:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Directive Test Fixture</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Style.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="../../../Libraries/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Widget.js"></script>
    <script src="./Fixture.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="BaseWidgetFixtures">
    <h1>Base Info Card</h1>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="one-template">
        <div>This is first template</div>
    </script>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="two-template">
        <div>This is second template</div>
    </script>
    <div ng-controller="InfoCardFixture">
        <bw-info-card title="title"></bw-info-card>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If I try to include the templates via NgInclude it however fails. I guess it tries to load the template for the directives before doing NgInclude (even though it is earlier in the file). The correct script tags are getting included on the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Directive Test Fixture</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Style.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="../../../Libraries/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Widget.js"></script>
    <script src="./Fixture.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="BaseWidgetFixtures">
    <h1>Base Info Card</h1>
    <div ng-include src="'templates.html'"></div>
    <div ng-controller="InfoCardFixture">
        <bw-info-card title="title"></bw-info-card>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there something that I am missing or can you not NgInclude templates for use with directives?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this discussing where Pete Bacon Darwin explains the order that directives are linked/compiled. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/3HsNz4ncnYA/discussion. You could probably rearange your html to get this working but this is not really what `ng-include` was meant to do. I'd recommend using something like [angular-templatecache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-angular-templatecache) if you don't want to load your templates with AJAX.

Comment: Is there a way without grunt/gulp? I dont want to run a listener. I dont think I mind putting them in one file manually so long as I can still include it into pages easily.

Comment: I saw this https://github.com/astik/angular-combine but I am struggling to get it to work without prior experience in bower. I was hoping for something easier like just a JS file.

Comment: Okay I think I figured it out. I just needed bower to pull down the latest version and then afterwards can just link in the angular-combine.min.js to the page. Right now I am just having all templates come from the cache (so regex is .*) I am not sure if this is an expected usage pattern though.